# Autofill formulas in multiple sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a problem to address, I have a Gsheet with many sheets that have columns with many formulas, for example I have a sheet AD that in the column A, N, O, P, Q, R, S , T , U, V , W , Y and Z have formulas. I have solved it with the script that I put here but it takes too long.

The thing is that in this Gsheet I have more sheets with as many formulas as the AD sheet, I have a MAIL etc sheet that has formulas in skipped columns, how can I optimize the script so that it copies formulas in the column that has formulas and drags them to the last column with data?

`

```
function autoFill(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var hojaAD = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('AD');

  var copiaA2 = hojaAD.getRange('A2');
  var destinationRangeA = hojaAD.getRange(2,1,hojaAD.getLastRow()-1); //el 2 es la fila y el 1 la column
  copiaA2.copyTo(destinationRangeA);  

  var copiaO2 = hojaAD.getRange('O2');
  var destinationRangeO = hojaAD.getRange(2,15,hojaAD.getLastRow()-1); //el 2 es la fila y el 1 la column
  copiaO2.copyTo(destinationRangeO);

  var copiaP2 = hojaAD.getRange('P2');
  var destinationRangeP = hojaAD.getRange(2,16,hojaAD.getLastRow()-1); //el 2 es la fila y el 1 la column
  copiaP2.copyTo(destinationRangeP);

  var copiaQ2 = hojaAD.getRange('Q2');
  var destinationRangeQ = hojaAD.getRange(2,17,hojaAD.getLastRow()-1); //el 2 es la fila y el 1 la column
  copiaQ2.copyTo(destinationRangeQ);

  var copiaR2 = hojaAD.getRange('R2');
  var destinationRangeR = hojaAD.getRange(2,18,hojaAD.getLastRow()-1); //el 2 es la fila y el 1 la column
  copiaR2.copyTo(destinationRangeR);

  var copiaS2 = hojaAD.getRange('S2');
  var destinationRangeS = hojaAD.getRange(2,19,hojaAD.getLastRow()-1); //el 2 es la fila y el 1 la column
  copiaS2.copyTo(destinationRangeS);

  var copiaT2 = hojaAD.getRange('T2');
  var destinationRangeT = hojaAD.getRange(2,20,hojaAD.getLastRow()-1); //el 2 es la fila y el 1 la column
  copiaT2.copyTo(destinationRangeT);
  
  var copiaU2 = hojaAD.getRange('U2');
  var destinationRangeU = hojaAD.getRange(2,21,hojaAD.getLastRow()-1); //el 2 es la fila y el 1 la column
  copiaU2.copyTo(destinationRangeU);

  var copiaV2 = hojaAD.getRange('V2');
  var destinationRangeV = hojaAD.getRange(2,22,hojaAD.getLastRow()-1); //el 2 es la fila y el 1 la column
  copiaV2.copyTo(destinationRangeV);

  var copiaW2 = hojaAD.getRange('W2');
  var destinationRangeW = hojaAD.getRange(2,23,hojaAD.getLastRow()-1); //el 2 es la fila y el 1 la column
  copiaW2.copyTo(destinationRangeW);

  var copiaY2 = hojaAD.getRange('Y2');
  var destinationRangeY = hojaAD.getRange(2,25,hojaAD.getLastRow()-1); //el 2 es la fila y el 1 la column
  copiaY2.copyTo(destinationRangeY);

   var copiaZ2 = hojaAD.getRange('Z2');
  var destinationRangeZ = hojaAD.getRange(2,26,hojaAD.getLastRow()-1); //el 2 es la fila y el 1 la column
  copiaZ2.copyTo(destinationRangeZ);
}
```

`

I have tried to make a script but it is slow

Comment: I would start by grouping the adjacent columns. In your example you could do only two or three copy instructions, one for the A column and the other/s for the "O:Z" columns (it looks you might have skipped "X", if that were the case you would need two groups). E.g. in your example you would use a .getRange('O2:Z2') for your "copia" variable and paste it in the first destination cell/row combination, for the desired number of rows.

Comment: "I have solved it with the script that I put here but it takes too long." Too long is a very subjective definition, and it may also depend on the formulas being copied. Would you please describe how long your script takes to run and the nature of the formula in row 2.

Comment: @GiampaoloFerradini Perhaps "O2:W2", skip Column X, and then "Y2:Z2".

Comment: If I group on the copia variable O2:Z2, how can I skip the X column?  and lastly for the destinationrange variable, how should I position it to paste into the first destination cell/row combination, for the desired number of rows?

Thanks

Comment: _If I group on the copia variable O2:Z2, how can I skip the X column?_ You don't group on O2:Z2, you group on O2:W2, then Y2:Z2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping columns as suggested by @GiampaoloFerradini.

Instead of 12 discrete columns, the function applies to three discrete groups:

- Column A
- Column O-W inclusive
- Column Y-Z inclusive

Column X is omitted; just as it is not part of the discrete columns in the OP script.

```
function autoFill(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var hojaAD = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('AD');
  
  // CopiaA2
  var copiaA2 = hojaAD.getRange(2,1)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: copiaA2 is "+copiaA2.getA1Notation())
  var copiaA2LR = hojaAD.getLastRow()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: last row = "+copiaA2LR)
  var destinationRangeA = hojaAD.getRange(2,1,(copiaA2LR-1),1)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: destination rangeA = "+destinationRangeA.getA1Notation())
  copiaA2.copyTo(destinationRangeA)

  // CopiaO2-W2
  var copiaOW2 = hojaAD.getRange(2,15,1,9)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: copiaOW2 is "+copiaOW2.getA1Notation())
  var destinationRangeOW = hojaAD.getRange(2,15,(copiaA2LR-1),9)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: destination rangeOW = "+destinationRangeOW.getA1Notation())
  copiaOW2.copyTo(destinationRangeOW)

  // CopiaY2-Z2
  var copiaYZ2 = hojaAD.getRange(2,25,1,2)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: copiaYZ2 is "+copiaYZ2.getA1Notation())
  var destinationRangeYZ = hojaAD.getRange(2,25,(copiaA2LR-1),2)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: destination rangeYZ = "+destinationRangeYZ.getA1Notation())
  copiaYZ2.copyTo(destinationRangeYZ)
  
}
```